# Rails 3: How to create a related record from an index page

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new to Rails. Feel free to edit the question title.
Some of this may be obvious to you. (I hope!)

I have an *auction* which has many *lots* (items for sale).
I've set up the auctions, I can add/edit/delete just fine.

I want to be able to view/add/delete lots from one page from a URL like /auctions/1/lots/ so I set up my routes like so:

```
resources :auctions, :except => :edit do
  resources :lots
end
```

My models look like this:

```
class Auction < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :lots
end

class Lot < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :auction
  ...
end
```

My lots_controller.rb looks like this:

```
def index
  @auction = Auction.find(params[:auction_id])
  @lots = @auction.lots
end
```

My lots/index.html.erb file:

```
<ul>
<% @lots.each do |lot| %>
  <li><%= lot.description %></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

This renders the lots just fine.
The problem is when I try to put a form for creating new lots. I'm not sure of what I need to put where.

```
<%= form_for(@auction.lots.build) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :description %>
<% end %>
```

Adding that gives me the following error when viewing the page:
`` undefined method `lots_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fb77ea26308>:0x007fb77d43fd00> ``

I was under the impression that `@auction.lots.build` was the correct argument to put there.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`form_for` is trying to infer the action path from the new Lot entity (and failing).  You can just specify the `:url` directly:

```
<%= form_for(@auction.lots.build, url: auction_lots_path(@auction)) do |f| %>
```

Alternatively, pass an array to indicate to form_for that this resource is nested:

```
<%= form_for([@auction, @auction.lots.build]) do |f| %>
```

Comment: I used the first solution, and it worked for the most part. The page loads, I see the flash message, the record is created but the auction_id isn't populated in it.

Comment: Can you post what your `create` action looks like, and what params are being passed to it (you can see this in your logs)?  Also, I changed the `:url` to use the `auction_lots_path` instead of `new_auction_lot_path` - see if that helps.

Comment: My create action wasn't right. It was just `@auction = Auction.find(params[:auction_id])`. I added `@lot = @auction.lots.build(params[:lot])` and now it works.

Comment: I assumed you meant `auction_lots_path` anyway, which is what I needed and worked.